# PHP/MySQL result to process multiple records

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building a payment module which processes a customers account once a month. I have a query which gets all the customer payment items for the given month, sums the amount and then sends the data to the payment gateway. This works great and I receive back confirmation from the bank yes or no. If yes I then need to update all the items which were in the request with the invoice number. I am getting the sum using a while loop and this is performed before the request is sent. The gateway can only process a single request and I don't want to loop through each invoice item for each request, I would rather perform a single request for all outstanding invoice items.

Some code is:

```
$get_payment_items_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_invoice_item WHERE billing_cycle = date");

while($get_payment_items_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_payment_items_query)){
    $invoice_amount = $invoice_amount + $get_payment_items_result['payment_amount'];
}
```

then later after I get the response back from the bank I am adding a record to the invoice table and getting the invoice id and then do:

```
$update_payment_item_query = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_invoice_item SET status = '" . PAYMENTCOMPLETE . "', invoice_id = '$invoice_id' WHERE invoice_item_id = '" . $get_payment_items_result['invoice_item_id'] . "'");
```

This only updates a single record because the update query is outside the while loop. I know there is a way to store the record identifier in a string/array and perform a single update query but I don't really know the name for something like that so haven't been able to find an example.

I hope that makes sense but here is some more detail.

There are 5 items ready to be invoiced. I get the total amount of the 5 items. I then make a single request to the payment gateway to charge for the 5 items. The bank send back a response yes or no. If yes, I then generate an invoice id for the payment. I then need to update the 5 items with the newly created invoice id. The updating the 5 items in a single query is where I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question right but you could use a sub-query in your where. Use the first query in where of second query:

WHERE invoice_item_id IN (SELECT invoice_item_id FROM tbl_invoice_item WHERE billing_cycle = date)

Comment: Oh yes, moreover you do not need the while that using the first query, simply use SUM as described below.

Comment: How would I then update the multiple invoice items once I get a response back from the payment gateway. Say the payment request had 5 item amounts all summed together, the payment has been accepted by the bank, I then generate an invoice for that payment and then I need to update the 5 items with the new invoice id. At that point I would need to perform another query to refetch the 5 items id's so I could update with the new invoice id.

Comment: But this is exactly what you will do with a subquery. Instead of generating a string containing the ids must be updated and use it in where you can ask these ids directly using the same first query. When you use UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...) is the same of UPDATE ... WHERE id IN ( your_concat_ids ).

Comment: Query for get invoice amount:

SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM tbl_invoice_item WHERE billing_cycle = date

Query for update response payment

UPDATE tbl_invoice_item SET status = '" . PAYMENTCOMPLETE . "', invoice_id = '$invoice_id' WHERE invoice_item_id IN (SELECT invoice_item_id FROM tbl_invoice_item WHERE billing_cycle = date)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I am using a WHERE IN clause.

In the while loop I create a variable to hold the items which need to be updated

```
$invoice_item_id .= $get_payment_items_result['invoice_item_id'] . ',';
```

I then remove the last comma using substring_replace then in the update query I use

```
WHERE invoice_item_id IN (" . $invoice_item_array . ")
```

Seems to work OK.